# Calling an external class only once?

Tags: php

I have a class that using an external package to do something

```
class MyClass
{
    public function doSomething($data){
        $external = new External();
        $external->doSomething($data);
    }
}
```

This class is called from another class, for example:

```
class MasterClass
{
    public function go(){

        $data = 'whatever';
        $data2 = 'whatever2';

        $myClass = new MyClass();
        $myClass->doSomething($data);
        $myClass->doSomething($data2);
        ....
    }
}
```

So in my MasterClass I am calling the doSomething function multiple times. WHich creates a new External class multiple times - which is not really necessary.

How can I get around this issue and only create the external class once?

Comment: Create the external class in the function go, or create it as a property of MyClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `External` class in constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
    private $external;

    public function __construct(External $external)
    {
        $this->external = $external;
    }

    public function doSomething($data) 
    {
        $this->external->doSomething($data);
    }

class MasterClass
{
    public function go() {

        $data = 'whatever';
        $data2 = 'whatever2';

        $external = new External();        

        $myClass = new MyClass($external);
        $myClass->doSomething($data);
        $myClass->doSomething($data2);
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should the caller have to know about the construction of `$external`?

Comment: @syck, it seems to make sense since External is a dependency here.

Comment: @syck Class `MyClass` is dependency for `MasterClass` so should be passed by constructor also `External` is dependency for `MasterClass` etc. etc. It's The Dependency Inversion Principle.

Comment: You don't need to pass in _every_ class, only the ones you care about decoupling. It's hard to say based on the information given if that would be the right thing to do.

Comment: To encapsulate `$external` you would have to use an additional wrapper, if you follow this proposal.

Comment: @Adam decoupling is always the right thing to do but not always it is unnecessary.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  Ideally, you would take it a step further and code to an interface like ExternalInterface.  Therefore you aren't stuck depending on the logic within the External class, you can swap it out with another class that implements this interface as needed without having to modify MyClass.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass
{
   protected $external;

   public function doSomething($data){
        if(!$this->external){
            $this->external = new External();
        }
        $this->external->doSomething($data);
   }
}
```

But read about dependency injection in php.

Comment: Thanks, could you show me an example with dependency injection.

Comment: @panthro Look at Grzegorz Gajda's answer if you want to see dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks Devon, I will.

Comment: @panthro To big to give a simple example here. You have to understand the principle behind that, then you can use it for your code. And my answer is not dependency injection!!

Comment: @panthro  `dependency injection`  Basicly means new use `new Class();` within a class, always inject the instacne that is needed in the class.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `new External()` call into the constructor and store it as a property, then reference that property in the `doSomething()` method instead of constructing a new instance every time.

Alternatively, if you don't want to always construct a new `External` whenever you construct a `MyClass`, you could move the construction into a **Lazy Load** static method called something like `getExternal()` in `External` class.

The first time that method is called it would need to store a new instance of `External` as a property, but on subsequent calls (when the property is already set) return the same instance. This type of pattern is called **Singleton Pattern** in Object-Oriented Design Patterns.

You could refer to this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to know more about singleton pattern and how it is implemented.

Comment: Thank you for being the only sane person in the thread and using the constuctor.  Everyone else is trying to overcomplicate this with DI & interfaces or they're trying to initialize the object inside the method.

Comment: This is the best explanation for this concept.